# Cordova plugin read preferences from XML in swift

Tags: ios, swift, cordova, ionic-framework

In my cordova plugin I have declared in the plugin.xml this preference

```
 <preference name="apiKey" value="yourApiKeyHere" />
```

I know how to read in OBJ C

```
NSString* apiKey = [self.commandDelegate.settings objectForKey:[@"apiKey" lowercaseString]];
```

But how I can read using swift instead obj c?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In swift the settings are stored inside the *"same"* settings [`dictionary`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary), you just need to access it differently.

So your code become something like

```swift
let apiKey = self.commandDelegate.settings["apiKey".lowercased()] as? NSString;
```